# How Do I Request "Send Email As You" Scope?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps script deployed as a Web Application, and then I have a web app. hosted at www.mjpanel.com, that calls the Google Apps script as a web service.  In the www.mjpanel.com app, I synch. up with Google requesting the following scopes:

.init(
                {
                    client_id: '[Client ID].apps.googleusercontent.com',
                    fetch_basic_profile: true,
                    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://mail.google.com https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
                }
            );

This includes the request I can find for 'all gmail authorization'.  When that call issues and the authorization box pops up telling them what my app. is requesting to do, one of the items is "Send Email On Your Behalf".

My Google Apps Script needs the permission to "Send Email As You", which is different than "Send Email On Your Behalf".  Thus, when the app. reaches a point that it is going to issue a web service request to my Google Apps script that exercises the code to "Send Email As You", the web service call is failing due to the lack of permission.  If I debug, capture the Google Apps script URL that the web service call is getting sent to, and paste into a browser tab, I get a return that is the button for the user to authorize my app. to "Send Email As You".

However, that is no good, because this is happening as a Web Service call.

What I need is a way to request the "Send Email As You" scope up front; but I can't find any documentation that tells me how to frame that scope request.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail`.

To force a script to request that, you can write a commented use of `MailApp` e.g.

```
// MailApp.sendEmail();
```

It won't do anything but it will get detected by Apps Script which will prompt for authorization.